# How to reset/renew DHCP in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

I want to reset/renew the DHCP in android through code so is there any way/command to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the WifiManager methods: call [disconnect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#disconnect%28%29), then [reconnect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#reconnect%28%29). You'll need to make sure you have the appropriate permission: I think you'll need `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` at a minimum.

See if that works for you.